# How to find the week number of a given date in Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6, windows-8.1

Has anyone a working function that returns the week number of a given date in vb6?

This used to work:

```
Dim W As Integer

W = Format(DateSerial(2010, 1, 1), "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

But in Windows 8.1 you now get "Out of stack space".

Comment: I *knew* we should've stayed on XP!

Comment: Use the `DatePart` function, not `Format$` (and never `Format`).

Comment: It's strange, but I tried it out on 8.1 and `DatePart("ww", DateSerial(2010, 1, 1), ...` works. `Format(CDate("1/1/2010"), "ww", ...` also works. But `Format(DateSerial(...` causes the out of stack space error.

Comment: @jac: Have you tried assigning your date to a variable first then `Format`ting afterward?

Comment: @Westie I did not try that. It isn't my problem so I didn't care enough to dig that deep, and it is an easy enough work around. I just found it curious, and without doing any actual investigation I am thinking that it has something to do with the DateSerial function returning a variant of type date combined with the Format statement also returning a variant.

Comment: Thanks. That solves it. Let´s hope not lots of other things also is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit more complex given the offsets

The following function should work well for what you need. Simply pass it a valid Date object, and it will return an Integer of the Week number.

```
Private Function Week(dteValue As Date) As Integer
   'Monday is set as first day of week
   Dim lngDate As Long
   Dim intWeek As Integer

   'If january 1. is later then thursday, january 1. is not in week 1
   If Not Weekday("01/01/" & Year(dteValue), vbMonday) > 4 Then
      intWeek = 1
   Else
      intWeek = 0
   End If
   'Sets long-value for january 1.
   lngDate = CLng(CDate("01/01/" & Year(dteValue)))

   'Finds the first monday of year
   lngDate = lngDate + (8 - Weekday("01/01/" & Year(dteValue), vbMonday))
   'Increases week by week until set date is passed
   While Not lngDate > CLng(CDate(dteValue))
      intWeek = intWeek + 1
      lngDate = lngDate + 7
   Wend
   'If the date set is not in week 1, this finds latest week previous year
   If intWeek = 0 Then
      intWeek = Week("31/12/" & Year(dteValue) - 1)
   End If
   Week = intWeek
End Function
```

This code is courtesy of [FreeVBCode.com](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7369)  (included a reference to give attribute to the original author).

Comment: @finch - December 29, 2014, **IS NOT** the first week.

Comment: Under the ISO definition of week numbers, December 29, 2014, IS the first week of 2015. See [Wikipedia article on ISO week numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). One challenge is to agree _which_ week number is required. This has not been clearly addressed within the discussion.

Comment: @finch - it is the LAST week of 2014 ..... First.  Use your brain > wikipedia.  What YEAR is that date in,.... 2015 ... or 2014....  so,  why would the counter start at 1 mid 2014.  In any case, if it really bothers you, then simple fix to do  "if intWeek > 52 then intWeek = intWeek - 52" ... which would be wrong.  Function returns an int value ... if you pass some date in 2014 ... it will return what week that is in 2014 ---  if it returns 1 for day 354,  then it would be wrong as week 1 is for day 1-7 only.  Anything further, and you are just trolling.

Comment: I specified the ISO week number, not other week numbering systems. The article I referred to says _The first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of the year (and, hence, always contains 4 January)_. As December 29 2014 is Monday and January 1 2015 is Thursday, this week contains the first Thursday of the year and _under ISO week numbering system_ is the first week of 2015. Other week numbering systems may assign different week numbers. Which is why the question needs to define **which week numbering system do we want?**